# Problems connecting via serial to usb port to PCengines APU board using HL-340

Tags: debian, serial-console, minicom

To connect to my APU board via serial line, I bought a QinHeng Electronics HL-340. My operating system is Debian Linux 9.4

What ever I try, I only see junk displayed on screen or the cursor jumping around. PCEngines documentation tells me that their APU boards use 115200 8N1 for their serial console.

https://www.pcengines.ch/ht_com.htm

So I am using that in minicom. Hardware flow control and software flow control are both off.

```
CTRL-A Z for help | 115200 8N1 | NOR | Minicom 2.7 | VT102 | Offline | ttyUSB0
```

dmesg

```
[ 9947.078152] usb 2-1.1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
```

I also checked the gender changer cable, and it has pins 2 and 3 swapped.

I also tried it with

```
cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 115200
```

with the same result.

As well as other common baud rates (9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200).

I also tried to modprobe ch341 to load the correct kernel driver but that also did not work.

Removing the module lists

```
modprobe -vr ch341
rmmod ch41
rmmod usbserial

modprobe -v
insmod /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/drivers/serial/usbserial.ko
insmod /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/drivers/serial/ch341.ko
```

What else can I try?

Comment: First thing I'd do is store date from several attempts, and look at and compare their `hexdump` to see if something indicates the problem. "Cursor jumping around" probably means control characters.

Comment: @GAD3R I am on Linux...